# How do I increase the memory limit for my GWT app in dev mode?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I often get an OutOfMemory error in Eclipse when the local server reloads the last modifications.

Comment: Are you using Firefox, by chance?

Answer (score 1):

I set the maximum memory amount to 2048:

```
-Xms40m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

and the error rarely occurs.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Click the dropdown next to the "**Run**" button > **Run Configurations**.

In the "**Arguments**" tab, type in your desired memory values in the "**VM Arguments**" box.